# Чем плохи кастомные атрибуты

Tags: html

Слышал о том, что кастомные атрибуты это не есть хорошо.

По этому часто использую связку `data-кастомный атрибут`, но я ни разу не натыкался на достоверность слов выше.
Из личного опыта знаю только то, что кастомный не пройдёт валидацию и всё.

К каким проблемам могут привести кастомные атрибуты?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если на одной маленькой страничке использовать свои атрибуты - в этом наверно нет ничего страшного. А представьте, что у вас огромный проект, используете везде свои атрибуты, а через годик - оппа, ввели новый HTML атрибут, и он совпадает с вашим) Такое маловероятно, но чтобы избежать этих случаев, захочется добавить свой неповторимый "префикс" из серии `myAttr007-class="..." myAttr007-bubu="..."` вместо таких заморочек, в стандарте уже есть готовый `data-`

К тому же, если есть условный `data-bubu="100500"` то в JavaScript его можно достать и менять значение и́ через `elem.dataset.bubu`, и́ `elem.getAttribute / setAttribute`. А изменение атрибута - синхронно меняет и свойство dataset (и наоборот). Можно использовать то, что удобнее. А в случае с личными атрибутами, есть отдельное свойство с этим названием, и отдельный атрибут... они не зависят друг от друга, что не удобно:

```js
let bubu = document.getElementById('bubu');

console.log(bubu.bubufication); // undefined

bubu.bubufication = 100500;
console.log(bubu.bubufication);

console.log(bubu.getAttribute('bubufication')); // 1
```

```html
<div id="bubu" bubufication="1">test</div>
```

P.s. не проходят валидацию на [w3.org](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)